# OpenCV/Python: MedianBlur filter produces a black image

Tags: python, opencv, filtering, noise

I'm using OpenCV in python 2.7.

I'm trying to add noise to a grayscale image like:

```
localvar = skimage.util.random_noise(imgray, mode="localvar")
```

And then I'm trying to use `MedianBlur` filter to reduce the noise like

```
median_blur = cv2.medianBlur(localvar.astype(np.uint8),3)
```

But when I'm trying to show `median_blur` image, I get an almost black image.

```
plt.subplot(133),plt.imshow(median_blur, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Median Filter'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I have to convert `medianBlur` image input, in my example `localvar` image to `float32`.

Here is the solution:

```
median_blur = cv2.medianBlur(np.float32(localvar),3)
```

Comment: any particular reason for converting it to `float32` ?